# Summation from 0 to n of cos((k/n)2 pi)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

Recently I came across this summation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\cos\Bigl(k\frac{2\pi}{n}\Bigr)$$ when I was trying to evaluate the following summation $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k+z^{-k}$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}, z=\operatorname{cis}(\frac{2\pi}{n})$

But I got stuck... Could anyone give me a tip ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a particular case makes the situation simpler. What happens for $n=2,3,4,5$ for instance? Is there a formula for $1+z+z^2+\dots+z^n$? And if we take $^z {-1}$ instead of $z$?

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192065/evaluation-of-sum-k-0n-cos-k-theta?

Comment: Make the appropriate substitutions in [$\sum \cos$ when angles are in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n z^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n z^{-k}=z\frac{1-z^{-(n+1)}}{z-1}$

Is that where you started.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation this helped me a lot I couldn't see these 2 geometric progressions now I'm able to move on!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\cos\dfrac{2k\pi}n$ is the real part of $\:\Bigl(\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}n}\Bigr)^{\!k}$.

Comment: A better hint is to write $z = \Bigl(\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}n}\Bigr)$ and then go to the OP, where we know about $\sum(z^k+z^{-k})$, but we maybe do not know that it is $\left(\sum z^k\right)+\left(\sum z^{-k}\right)$...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I'll try to understand a bit better about Euler's notation for complex numbers

Comment: Note that, for the same price, considering the imaginary part, you obtain the sum of the sines.